# Existence of open sets $U, V$ of matrices such that for every $A \in U$ there exists $B \in V$ such that $B^4 = A$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

Prove there exist non-empty open sets U and V of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ such that for every matrix $A \in U$ there exists exactly one matrix $B \in V$ such that $B^4 = A$.

I've tried to approach this problem in several ways, using characteristic polynomials, Jordan Canonical Form and facts from calculus but failed to get anything useful.

Comment: I *think* you can take $U$ and $V$ both to be the set of matrices with $n$ distinct positive eigenvalues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: take $U$ to be a sufficiently small neighbourhood of the identity.  Recall the inverse function theorem.

Comment: i think the implicit function theorem might be more directly applicable, no? I know both are equivalent so it doesn't technically matter which we use... but it seems like implicit function theorem's hypothesis are very directly satisfied.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Depends on how you think about it.  I fixed the identity and use the inverse function theorem because the derivative of matrix fourth power at identity is invertible, so is a local diffeomorphism and be done with it.  You take two copies and compute the derivative, etc.

Comment: perhaps, it's just that with implicit function theorem, the proof was immediate in my head. but regardless, this is a very good hint! usually people learn (multivariable) calculus and linear algebra as separate subjects so it might not even occur to them that uniting both subjects gives an elegant answer

Answer (score 1):

Using the implicit function theorem, we can obtain a general result.

Let $B_0\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, $spectrum(B_0)=(\lambda_i)$, ${B_0}^4=A_0$, $f:X\rightarrow X^4$.

$\textbf{Proposition}$. If, for every $(i,j)$, $\lambda_i^3+\lambda_j^3+\lambda_i\lambda_j^2+\lambda_i^2\lambda_j\not= 0$, then there are open neighborhoods $V,U$ of $B_0,A_0$ s.t. $f$ is a diffeomorphism from $V$ onto $U$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. It suffices to show that the derivative $Df_{B_0}:H\in M_n\mapsto HB_0^3+B_0HB_0^2+B_0^2HB_0+B_0^3H$ is one to one.

If we stack row by row the matrices into vectors, then

$Df_{B_0}=I\otimes {B_0^3}^T+B_0\otimes {B_0^2}^T+B_0^2\otimes B_0^T+B_0^3\otimes I$. cf.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Since the $4$ above linear applications pairwise commute,  $spectrum(Df_{B_0})=(\lambda_i^3+\lambda_j^3+\lambda_i\lambda_j^2+\lambda_i^2\lambda_j)_{i,j}$ and we are done.

Note that, when $B_0=I$, all considered eigenvalues are equal to $4$.